# AWS certificate "https" issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, https

i am  facing some issue with my acm certificate and its connection to my website.

i have already linked my ACM's certificate to my loadbalancer and also fixed route53. but i didn't know where did i go wrong? or why it is only happening to me? In my ACM dashboard, it says - the certificate is "issued" and "in use" category it says "yes" but i don't know when i try to browse my website with "https" as prefix it says "this page isn't working" i don't know why this is happenning?

moreover when i try to browse the website through my own admin pc it gives me ssl image with a lock but with no content i.e, no page is displayed (nothing is displayed on my screen except the url). but when i try to browse this with without secured connection i.e, with "http" as prefix i can easily see my wordpress page on it.

please help me in this issue i am stucked in this from last 4 days . i am all tired by asking everyone for help but sadly no one response to me. you all guys are my last hope.

Comment: do you any error you hit your website with `https` ? did you inspect request in chrome? it might be because of mix content? whats the tarhget health of LB in case of HTTPS? without these information how one can help?

Comment: yeah i think it is mixed content cause when i inspect thorough it says

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[mixed content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content/How_to_fix_website_with_mixed_content)** is refer to an error where you have `HTTP+HTTPS` content over domain using `https://exampe.com`.

- Inspect request in browser
- Convert all these requests to `HTTPS`
- If backend API, Place `HTTPS` on backend API

Once you convert all `HTTP` request to `HTTPS` you will be able to access the website over `https://example.com`.

Comment: so do i need to edit http in my inspect tab to "https" ? if not please suggest me how can i convert all these requests to https. (i am new at both aws and stack overflow so i think you will definitely ignore my mistakes) sorry for what i have done above cause comment was not allowing me to  add so much text.

Comment: if you site is wordpress then you can look into this https://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-fix-the-mixed-content-error-in-wordpress-step-by-step/

Comment: hey i think i resolved the issue. thank you , but what about when i just normally browse my domain name in the url it is sending my to unsecure site. although when i browse my site "https" as prefix it works fine now. but i want to know why my "http" is not automatically redirecting it to "https"

Comment: There is no redirection by default unless you configured.

Comment: please help me in redirecting "http" to "https"

Comment: you can post another question as this is something really different.

Comment: okay please reply to my last question it is related to aws only. My aws certificate is showing valid for 1 month only how can i extend it for one year. Thank you in advance

Comment: you can use AWS certificate ACM, its free and its valid for one year

Comment: yeah i have used that certificate only but i don't know why it is showing for only one month

Comment: I see, you can add multiple ssl with LB. generate new one for one year and attach it to LB